# Play 2.x separate js css and assets folder

Tags: playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3

We're also using angularjs, so public/templates/*.html, public assets and app/assets files are mixed with the whole project including controllers or other server code. For our development, frontend dev wants to work under a clean project that contains these public assets.

How can I separate web assets from play 2.x project? I know Play support subproject. Other than sub project, is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new `Controller` that would serve these assets from an external folder. I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146586/play-additional-public-assets-directory/22149433).