# Sbt dist cause no access to unmanaged resources?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playback

With my sbt - play/scala application, I have been using sbt run while developing.
Almost finished my project, and now I want to sbt dist for production purposes.
(Correct me if this is a bad idea.)

My question is here.

With my sbt run, I had the access to unmanaged resources by adding

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Assets += baseDirectory.value / "works"
```

to my build.sbt

However, after sbt dist the same url no longer works and sends me 404 not found error.

```
Not Found For request 'GET /assets/RAW/abc.png'
```

This "works" folder includes files that will be generated during the service, which is separate directory from the usual "public" folder.

And This is my routes FYI.

```
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
GET     /works/*file                controllers.Assets.at(path="/works/", file)
```

Does sbt-dist requires any additional code in build.sbt or should I fix anything?

Comment: using sbt.version=0.13.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so here is how I solved my problem. 
After hours(probably days) of research, I was able to get an access to external files by adding a new function in controllers, `sendfile(new file(filename), inline=true)`

I also had to set routes. In my case, 
    GET     /download/:id/:name  controllers.DownloadTask.download(id: String, name: String)

After adding this url/routes info in the client, it worked well.

Answer (score 1):

[Additional asset directories](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/SBTCookbook#Add-additional-asset-directory) specified via `unmanagedResourceDirectories`

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Assets += baseDirectory.value / "works"
```

will also be served from `public` according to [docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/Migration23#sbt-web):

> A nuance with sbt-web is that all assets are served from the public
>   folder... note that the files there will be aggregated into the target public folder

This means you need to change `GET /works` route from

```
GET     /works/*file                controllers.Assets.at(path="/works/", file)
```

to

```
GET     /works/*file                controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

Additional assets should now be accessible at both

```
http://example.com/assets/RAW/abc.png
http://example.com/works/RAW/abc.png
```

You can confirm that additional assets end up under `public` after `sbt dist` by unzipping the generated package at `.../target/universal`, and then listing the contents of a `jar` under `lib` directory ending with `-assets.jar`, for example:

```
jar tf target/universal/play-scala-starter-example-1.0-SNAPSHOT/play-scala-starter-example.play-scala-starter-example-1.0-SNAPSHOT-assets.jar
```

Comment: Get /works route from get/works/*file to get /works/*file?

Comment: Already have a default resource folder at public. Should i also give an identical path to additional route? These files are located under works directory.

Comment: @min Yes, because Play aggregates additional assets paths such as `works` under `public`, despite the fact you have it in a separate `works` directory.

Comment: Im heading to my office now, will update you if this works. Thank you by the way. – min 38 mins ago

Comment: this causes conflicts with the previous assets. 
[error]  <link rel="stylesheet" href='@routes.Assets.at("/public", "css/web/style.css")'>

Comment: [error] /home/min/project_web-1.0.1/target/scala-2.12/twirl/main/views/html/admn/errors.template.scala:31: too many arguments (2) for method at: (file: String)play.api.mvc.Call
times 47. 

additional error message: 
[error]         <link rel="stylesheet" href='@routes.Assets.at("/public", "css/error.css")'>
[error]                                                                   ^

it basically happens whereever I call public files.

Comment: I don't fully understand the idea of assests end up in the public folder. Aren't they supposed to be in the target and works as if it is in the public? I think because target no longer exists after sbt-dist, my previous works with loading resources in the web page failed.

Comment: What happens if you provide only single argument to `at` like so: `@routes.Assets.at("css/web/style.css")`

Comment: [error] /home/min/project_web-1.0/app/views/web/main.scala.html:42: not enough arguments for method at: (path: String, file: String)play.api.mvc.Call.
[error] Unspecified value parameter file.
[error]     <script src="@routes.Assets.at("js/web/pace.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: maybe unzip location is the problem here? should i unzip the after sbt-dist under target/universal? but this may severely destroy the structure my codes.. I am unzipping this dist ver. at the same level as my dev ver.

Comment: If you unzip the package, can you see your assets from `works` in `lib/*-assets.jar`? You can use `jar tf` to list the contents of the jar.

Comment: yes, I can see what was in my works directory. but the issues are I am adding more files dynamically to this directory while actually running the app.

Comment: I see. Have you considered storing these dynamically generated assets in an external directory as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22146586/play-additional-public-assets-directory#answer-22149433

Comment: that answer provides Action` that serves a static resource and my cases related to dynamic resources? 
I think this topic is gradually heading to a different direction.
Issues are: 
1. I am trying to get dynamic resources access (files created after compiled and distributed, users upload) - by url https://URL:9000/assets/min/abc.png
2. Worked fine with unmanagedResourceDirectories in Assests while sbt run
3. No access to files when sbt dist and unzip with the same name.

Comment: or should i add some codes to activate build.sbt while
./bin/project_web -Dhttp.port=9001 with my unzipped universal dist?

Comment: Ok. so whenever I can access to the old files under works, generated before sbt dist. but not to the new files under works, generated after sbt dist and executed by ./bin/project_web and added by users.